# Compactness of $A \times B$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $A, B \subset \mathbb{R}$ be compact in $\mathbb{R}$. Show that $$A \times B = \{(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}:a\in A, b \in B\}$$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}^2$

I must show that $A \times B$ is closed and bounded. Since $A,B$ are compact then there exists an $M>0$ such that $|a|\le M$ and $|b|\le M$ but then how can I show that $A \times B$ is closed?

Comment: Hint: Assuming you're using the Euclidean distance on $\mathbb R^2$, you'll probably be interested in the quantity $\sqrt 2 M$.

Comment: I think you wanna prove $A\times B$ is closed since bounded have been shown.

Comment: @Zhang as it stands, the question seems to be "how can I show that $A\times B$ is bounded?" which hasn't actually been shown.

Comment: I guess you don't know tychonoffs compactness theorem, do you ?

Comment: @DominicMichaelis Nope, but I be sure to look it up. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Since $A$ is a compact subset of $\Bbb R$, there is an $M_A>0$ such that $|a|\le M_A$ for each $a\in A$. Similarly, there is an $M_B>0$ such that $|b|\le M_B$ for each $b\in B$. Now let $M=\max\{M_A,M_B\}$; then for any $\langle a,b\rangle\in A\times B$ we have $|a|,|b|\le M$, and therefore $a^2+b^2\le 2M^2$.

Comment: Thank you! How did you get $a^2+b^2\le 2M^2$?

Comment: @Tom: You’re welcome. If $|a|\le M$, then $a^2=|a|^2\le M^2$. Now do the same for $b$ and add the two inequalities.

Comment: How come we just can't add $a + b$ and get $a+b\le 2M$ ?

Comment: @Tom: You can, but the most straightforward way to show that a subset of the plane is bounded is to show that it lies in a disk centred at the origin; I was suggesting where you should look to get a big enough radius for that disk.

Comment: I see now, thanks again!

Comment: @Tom: You’re welcome!